# How to create/design custom bottom navigation bar in xamarin android and connect it to xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to use Tabbed Page with bottom tabs. I want to make custom bottom bar in android and use it or inflate it in TabbedPageRenderer. Is this possible? Can anyone help me?

I want to use something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/bottomtab.navarea" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_gravity="fill" 
android:layout_weight="1" /> 
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView android:id="@+id/bottomtab.tabbar" android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in my TabbedPageRenderer I want to use this layout for only the design of bottom bar.

Like you can access Toolbar and Tabbar from android. Similarly I want to access or create Bottombar.

Comment: what effect do you need ? If it's just plain style, just set it `On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);`

Comment: Using it. Now how to make a custom control of bottom bar like toolbar? I want to set the height of it and change the design.

Comment: you could refer to this:https://github.com/HoussemDellai/BottomBar-Xamarin-Forms/blob/master/BottomBarDemo/BottomBarDemo.Android/BottomBar/Renderers/BottomBarPageRenderer.cs